# Setting HttpRequestMessage.Content (json) for post SendAsync results in Unexpected character error

Tags: c#, httprequest, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

The setup:

1. (server) .Net Core 2 API
2. (client) AWS Lambda function coded in C# (sets the way the JWT has to be generated).
3. IDS3 using JWT (important for method of sending the request)

The IDS3 and JWT part are working fine. Making the call and hitting the .Net Core 2 API controller works fine.

The problem is that I get the following error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.\"]

The code, with explanations:

```
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(eventStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, myApiURL);
    requestMessage.Content = stringContent;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);
    HttpResponseMessage thing = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
    string actualResponse = thing.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;        
}
```

`eventStr` is a json string passed to the function handler by AWS.

`actualResponse` contains the erropr: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.\"]`

I've checked the StringContent being generated and it is absolutely correct.

What happens on the API side of things is that the JWT is found to be awesomely correct, the Controller constructor is fired, the action is never hit, ostensibly because the data payload (eventStr) isn't being attached to the `HttpRequestMessage` correctly.

Method signature for the API action:

```
          public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] string Message)
```

If that's not the right place, what is?

Comment: Show an example of the JSON being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the json.

So the AWS lambda function is sent an anonymous type by AWS. Basically just an quick and loose object.

I am required because of POST to send this as a string via the StringContent variable. If I serialize it, however, the Core API controller says "Hey, I know this! It's JSON. Let's deserialize it." And so it does.

Given that the action is expecting a string, the controller says "There are no actions that accept this object I have here. This is a Bad Request."

If, however, I send it as a pure string, (e.g. “{key1:value1”} instead of “{\”key1\”: \”value1\”}”)  with no quotes around the keys and values, the controller and action say "HEY! This is a string. I got this."

The problem then is that it's not valid json at that point, just something kind of like JSON. And so it's not treated correctly by the guts of the action.

For now and sans further knowledge and research, the workaround solution is to change the action signature to expect a parameter of type `Object` and deserialize it specifically within the method.

While this works, it doesn't feel like the right solution because I'm now essentially opening that call up to any object type instead of what we really want it to be. Which makes a kind of sense since the AWS Lambda function gets passed an anonymous type (i.e.: object).

Update: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers

This article goes over the types of solutions that you can use to rectify this problem. The short of it is that the Core API doesn't really know what to do with a string. There are several solutions the author lists. The one I chose to implement is extending the input formatter. I'll summarize some of the process here:

New class -> `RawRequestBodyFormatter : InputFormatter`

CTOR ->   `SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));`

`override Boolean CanRead`

`override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync`

Examine `context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType` to see if it contains your `text/plain` modifier.

In startup, add the following:

```
services.AddMvc(o => o.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawRequestBodyFormatter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Flurl](https://flurl.io/) library it will save you a lot of time.

So you can switch your code to the following (Please note that I commented on certain lines, you can remove those lines depending on the request usage):

```
try
{
    //Needed if request sent over Https
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    //OPTIONAL: set certificates validation, from a static container of global configuration
    Flurl.Configure(settings =>
    {
        settings.HttpClientFactory = new MyHttpClientFactory();
    });

    var result = await myApiUrl
        .WithHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {jwtToken}")
        .PostJsonAsync(requestMessage)
        .ReceiveString(); //For response as string
        .ReceiveJson<MyClass>(); // to map a json result to an object
}
catch(FlurlHttpException ex)
{
    throw ex.InnerException;
}
```

With the MyHttpClientFactory class:

```
public class MyHttpClientFactoryDev : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {   
        //If you want to validate all certs
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {

            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyError) => true

        };

        //If you need to verify certificate signature
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("path to cert"));

        return handler;

    }
}
```

Hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: Do you know how hefty that library is? The function making this call is an AWS Lambda function and they charge by time executing with reports down to the millisecond. My concern is making the execution time as lean as possible.

Comment: You didn't mention the performance aspect needed. Well in this case, an example of the json string would be highly appreciated, since the error is caused by this one, it could be a parsing error.

Comment: Adding a solution to explain what the actual problem and temporary solution is.

Comment: I've edited my solution with an article and summary of my approach in case you find it useful.